# Улучшение transition

Tags: css

При использовании `transition` увеличивается текст, но вместе с ним и сдвигаются все остальные элементы. Как сделать так, чтобы увеличивался только текст без изменений общей разметки.

з.ы. - знаю что это что-то нужно с `position` придумывать, но вот что и куда - увы не знаю.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnjmj7zu/2/ - код и стиль к нему

```css
nav {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 150px;
}
nav ul {
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-image: url(image/nab_back.png);
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #5c5656;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  font-size: 18pt;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tactics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Garison</a></li>
    <li><a href="professions.html">Professions</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Если не нравится сдвиг только по высоте - можно выставить `line-height` нужной величины

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте с `transform: scale(n)`

```css
nav {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 150px;
}
nav ul {
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-image: url(image/nab_back.png);
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #5c5656;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  display:inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Index</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Guides</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tactics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Garison</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Professions</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```